# Xcode5.0.1 and ios7.0.3 issue - xcode not stopping on click of stop

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, xcode5

This is happening after I upgraded to Xcode 5.0.1. When ever I try to stop the xcode it is not stopping. The simulator is remaining as blank. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this sometimes. It is entirely unrelated to project code and is some bug or issue with XCode. It also happened in earlier versions (XCode 4.x). No solution but to force quit.

Surprisingly, what worked for me was **going to iOS Simulator menu, and pressing "Reset Content and Settings".**